# Calculating Glass Wool Insulation Thickness

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer, thermal-conduction, thermal-insulation

I intend to calculate required thickness of glass wool insulation for a hot vessel. I know the temperature inside the vessel, the acceptable temperature at the surface of the vessel (after insulation), ambient temperature and the diameter of the vessel. However, I have no information about heat loss per meter of vessel.

Is it still possible to calculate the required thickness? Any reference literature would be extremely useful.

Comment: So check out heat transfer, conduction, convection and radiation. Even a simple google search gives https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/heat-loss-insulated-pipes-d_1151.html

Comment: You are right. But I intend to ask that what is the procedure to calculate required thickness of insulation. Like any handbook to insulation that guides you through that procedure.

Comment: Read Engineering Heat Transfer by Simonson. Formulae and explanations.